# AppInsights % of Failed Requests Per Day

Tags: azure-application-insights, kql

I'm trying to write a simple KQL AppInsights query that gives me the % of failed requests per day.

I want to end up with results like:

| Timestamp | ErrorPercentage |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-07-18 | 1.2 |
| 2023-07-19 | 1.1 |

I have this query that gets me the failed count per day:

```
requests
| where success == false
| where resultCode startswith "5"
| where ((operation_Name startswith "GET /my-path"))
| summarize failedCount=sum(itemCount) by Timestamp = bin(timestamp, 1d)
| sort by Timestamp asc
| project format_datetime(Timestamp, 'yyyy-MM-dd'), failedCount
```

Then i can obviously flip the `success` flag to get the succesful ones, but i'm not sure how to bring these two calculations together to get the one value `ErrorPercentage`.

Can someone please help? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try something similar to the following example, using the [`sumif()` aggregation function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/sumif-aggfunction):

```
requests
| where operation_Name startswith "GET /my-path"
| summarize failure_percentage =
    100.0 * sumif(itemCount, success == false and resultCode startswith "5") /
    sum(itemCount)
 by Timestamp = bin(timestamp, 1d)
| project format_datetime(Timestamp, 'yyyy-MM-dd'), failure_percentage
```